# Powershell - resolve path outside of a PSDrive alias

Tags: powershell

I have a very long path name which I created a PS-Drive for

```
new-psdrive -name blah -psprovider filesystem -root c:/foo/bar/bizz/bazz/grozz/grizz/blah/blow
```

I need to pass a file into an external tool which is having trouble resolving the path across the psdrive path.  How do I get the path to a file (say directly underneath the blah 
directory) bit with the full path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help ?

```
(Get-Item "blah:\yourfile.ps1").FullName
```

Comment: Thanks. Been wondering how to do this forever but only absolutely had to now.