# How to construct path with clearcase view name if only the drive letter is M:?

Tags: powershell, clearcase

Clearcase dynamic views can be accessed via M: drive by default.

But if it is mapped in some other drive letter like Y: it will not have View name.

This property is challenging when i am doing scripting . If the user trigger the script from M: drive the path should be constructed with view name.

I am using powershell, If i know how to get the clearcase view name i can construct the path dynamically.

```
$drive =$Pwd.Drive.Name
$ClearcaseViewName ="How to get current view name from the directory? "

If ( $Pwd.Drive.Name -eq "M" ) {
       $Path = "M:\$ClearcaseViewName\Vobname" 
}
Else { 
       $Path = "$Drive"+":"+"\VobName"
}
```

Is there any easy way to get clearcase name in powershell? Even cleartool commands can be used in powershell

Answer (score 0):

A drive letter for a ClearCase view (even a snapshot one actually) represent a [Windows `subst`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUBST), used for substituting paths on physical and logical drives as virtual drives.
See for illustration "[Getting present working view in Clearcase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24269353/6309)".

You can check if the following PS commands could help:

- "[Powershell - resolve path outside of a PSDrive alias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11747552/6309)":

  ```
  (Get-Item "blah:\yourfile.ps1").FullName`
  ```
- "[Use PowerShell to Work Easily with Drives and Paths](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/09/07/use-powershell-to-work-easily-with-drives-and-paths.aspx)"

  ```
  Get-Location
  ```

The goal is to resolve the `Y:` drive to its full path `M:\viewname\vobname\...` from which you can extract the view name.

> Even cleartool commands can be used in powershell

In that case, a [`cleartool pwv -root`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_pwv.htm?lang=en) can help too in order to get the ClearCase view name (if executed anywhere within the `Y:\` drive).
That was the approach chosen in the aforementioned "[Getting present working view in Clearcase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24269353/6309)".